# Object not refreshing when executing SP with EF

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am running an SP that updates a record then returns the updated record. The record returned indicates that no changes were made, but if I look at the record in the database directly, it is indeed updated. Any subsequent SP that selects that record returns the original version of the record.

Stored procedure:

```
[POSeries_UpdateWins]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@POSeriesID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @Team1 int
    DECLARE @Team2 int
    DECLARE @Team1Wins int
    DECLARE @Team2Wins int
    SELECT @Team1 = Team1ID, @Team2 = Team2ID
    FROM POSeries 
    WHERE POSeriesID = @POSeriesID

    DECLARE @Temp int
    SELECT @Temp = home
    FROM Results
    WHERE POSeriesID = @POSeriesID AND ((HomeID = @Team1 AND Home> Visitor) OR (VisitorID = @Team1 AND Visitor > Home))

    SELECT @Team1Wins = @@ROWCOUNT

    SELECT @Temp = home
    FROM Results
    WHERE POSeriesID = @POSeriesID AND ((HomeID = @Team2 AND Home> Visitor) OR (VisitorID = @Team2 AND Visitor > Home))

    SELECT @Team2Wins = @@ROWCOUNT

    UPDATE POSeries
    set Team1Wins = @Team1Wins, Team2Wins = @Team2Wins
    WHERE POSeriesID = @POSeriesID

    SELECT POSeriesID, SeasonID, POSeasonID, POBracketsID, Series, Team1ID, Team1Wins, Team1Rank, Team2ID, Team2Wins, Team2Rank, Round, Games, WinnerPlaysID, isComplete
    FROM POSeries
    WHERE POSeriesID = @POSeriesID
```

Method that calls the SP which is imported into the EF and is set to return the POSeries entity

```
Public Function POSeries_UpdateWins(ByVal mID As Integer) As POSeries

        Dim mPOSerieses As ObjectResult(Of POSeries) = mData.POSeries_UpdateWins(mID)
        Dim mPOSeries As POSeries = mPOSerieses.FirstOrDefault
        Return mPOSeries
    End Function
```

Code snippet where this is processed:

```
    Dim oPOSeries As List(Of POSeries) = mEDF.POSeries_SelByPOSeasonID(mSeasonID)
    For Each pos As POSeries In oPOSeries
        If pos.isComplete = False Then
            pos = mEDF.POSeries_UpdateWins(pos.POSeriesID)
            pos = mEDF.POSeries_SelByID(pos.POSeriesID)
            If pos.Team1Wins > (pos.Games / 2) Or pos.Team2Wins > (pos.Games / 2) Then
                pos.isComplete = True
                mEDF.POSeries_Save(pos)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

So basically when `mEDF.POSeries_UpdateWins` is called it returns the the object pos unchanged. But if I go into SSMS and run a

```
SELECT * ON POSeries WHERE POSeries = ID
```

it shows Team1Wins and Team2Wins updated correctly. Even running the `mEDF.POSeries_SelByID` after the fact still returns the unchanged record.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the initial SP run in the EF return the corrected record?

Answer (score 0):

You will not get right results in @@ROWCOUNT with SET NOCOUNT ON.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/12/02/sql-server-effect-of-set-no-count-on-rowcount/

Comment: Tried taking it out.....no change. It us updating the rows, no problem. It just isn't returning the updated row within EF. If I run a query is SMS while the debugger is paused right after the Update SP is run it shows the updated rows, but the next line running the select SP does not return proper results.